# SO_REUSEPORT and SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to sniff the frames that go through a certain port, so I have made socket listener with the options SO_REUSEPORT and SO_REUSEADDR before binding it. But where I launch my application, I only get my frames on the application side, not the listener.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SO_REUSEPORT / SO_REUSEADDR means that multiple processes can listen on the same port, however each connection (for TCP) or packet (for UDP/ICMP) will only go to a single process. So you can't sniff traffic this way because either (a) the other process gets the packets and your process doesn't or (b) your process gets the packets, but then the other one doesn't and thus won't respond to it.

To sniff the traffic you can use something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or libpcap/WinPCAP if you need to capture packets in a programatic manner.